# About Response.Redirect, FormsAuthentication and MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, response.redirect

I want to understand the difference in the behavior of a program when we call `FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage` vs. when we call `Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl())` and manually redirect.

Please see the comments below.

I have a `LoginController/Index` (two actions, one for `HttpGet` and one for `HttpPost`). The View of this controller represents the application's login page.

I also have a home page or landing page, i.e. the page that the user must be taken to after a successful login. This is represented in my application by the `HomeController's` `Index` action and the `~Views/Home/Index.cshtml` view.

I have presented three scenarios. I understand scenario 1 and I expect it to work the way it does, but I noted a difference in scenarios 2 and 3.

**Scenario 1**

```
namespace Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Login loginViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = ValidateUser(loginViewModel);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // Other stuff: set cookies, session state, etc.

                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid password. Please try again.");
                }
            }

            // If the user was a valid user, the flow-of-control won't reach here
            // as expected and the user will be taken to the view that is served
            // by the HomeController::Index() action. If it is by convention, it will 
            // be the ~Views/Home/Index.cshtml view. This is fine.
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2**

```
namespace Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Login loginViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = ValidateUser(loginViewModel);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // Other stuff: set cookies, session state, etc.

                    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(loginViewModel.UserName, 
                        loginViewModel.RememberMe));
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid password. Please try again.");
                }
            }

            // If the user was a valid user, the flow-of-control still reaches here
            // as expected. And as expected, it renders the same View, i.e. the View
            // associated with the controller we are in, which is ~Views/Login/Index, 
            // which represents the login page. This is wrong. I shouldn't redirect here.
            // I understand this. My question here is two fold:
            // 1) I am simply trying to understand the difference in behaviors of the three 
            //    scenarios described in this question.
            // 2) Given this, the right way would be to not use Response.Redirect here but instead
            //    use RedirectToAction. However, if I wanted to use Response.Redirect, what should
            //    I do?
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Scenario 3**

```
namespace Controllers
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Login loginViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var user = ValidateUser(loginViewModel);

                if (user != null)
                {
                    // Other stuff: set cookies, session state, etc.

                    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(loginViewModel.UserName, 
                        loginViewModel.RememberMe);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid password. Please try again.");
                }
            }

            // If the user was a valid user, the flow-of-control still reaches here
            // as expected. However, magically, somehow, even though the statement below
            // suggests that the user must be taken to the View of the same controller and
            // action that we are currently in, i.e. the View of the LoginController::Index()
            // action, i.e. the ~Views/Login/Index.cshtml, it magically takes me to the 
            // ~Views/Home/Index.cshtml instead, which is what is specified as the LoginPage
            // attribute of the <authentication>/<forms> element in the web.config.
            // I want to know how this happens.
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

I am at my wit's end now. Now, even **Scenario 1** that uses `RedirectToAction` is calling the `Index()` action on the `LoginController` class.

Answer (score 1):

The actual difference is that FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage() sets cookies and then makes redirects but FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl() only returns redirect url.

The funny thing is that implementation of FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl() is like this:

```
public static String GetRedirectUrl(String userName, bool createPersistentCookie)
{ 
    if (userName == null) 
        return null;
    return GetReturnUrl(true); 
}
```

So actually userName and createPersistentCookie parameters are completely ignored. You must call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( userName, true/false ) manually before calling GetRedirectUrl.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Vasily.
`RedirectFromLoginPage` issues an authentication ticket and places it in the default cookie using the `SetAuthCookie` method.
You can read something about this behavior [here](http://aleris.wordpress.com/2009/02/28/the-infamous-redirectfromloginpage-method/).

If you want to have a better control over the cookie creation you should (encryption, expiration, extending the principal) you should create the cookie yourself.
I explained the whole process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4939533/cookie-confusion-with-formsauthentication-setauthcookie-method/4940079#4940079) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030227/asp-net-mvc-let-user-switch-between-roles/5041584#5041584).