# Switch current role - .NET Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identity, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using .NET Core 3.1 with Identity.

I have an admin user with `roles = {Admin, Customer}` and other users with `roles = {User}`.
So I want the admin can switch role, with a dropdown in the corner like `"Switch to customer view"` and switch the current role to Customer, so he can see Customer view.

I was looking for and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030227/asp-net-mvc-let-user-switch-between-roles), its what I want, but the solution is using cookies.
I tried, and you can edit cookies in the chrome debugging console, so anyone can change to Admin.

Is there an option to achieve this, without cookies?

This is what i was using with cookies to set it:

```
HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("currentRole", "Admin",
    new CookieOptions { Expires = DateTime.Now.AddYears(10), IsEssential = true, 
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax, Secure = true });
```

And this for get it:

```
string currentRole = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["currentRole"];
```

Comment: A role is essentially a set of entitlements or permissions. So an admin user would always have all three roles because he is always allowed to do what all three of the roles permit. If you need to control the user experience at a finer level than that, you need some additional mechanism on top of roles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a cookie to store something like that as a preference doesn't seem problematic, as long as you're not using as the only factor on what the backend returns.

Consider the cookie as a request, not an entitlement: "Please show me the Admin experience," or "Please show me the Customer experience". When your backend receives that request, you can look at the preference that was passed in via the cookie just as you are now, but then check it against their authorization to see whether or not to honor it and proceed with whatever logic you're using to deliver that experience. If a customer passes in an "admin" cookie request but they're not in the "admin" role, you can reject it.